# Use windows form whilst command prompt is running

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

What I am working on is a program that runs a command on command prompt and outputs the outcome into the form. But whenever you start the command it locks up the windows form and then you can no longer click anything on the form. This is an issue because I want to add a stop button, please see below for the appropriate code.

```
private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C robocopy " + "\"" + source.Text + "\" \"" + Destination.Text + "\" /E /ZB /W:1 /R:3 /MT /A-:SH";
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        // see below for output handler
        proc.ErrorDataReceived += proc_DataReceived;
        proc.OutputDataReceived += proc_DataReceived;

        proc.Start();

        proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
        proc.BeginOutputReadLine();

        proc.WaitForExit();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the call to `proc.WaitForExit();` as this blocks execution. See [the docs] (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit(v=vs.110).aspx) about `WaitForExit`:

> Sets the period of time to wait for the associated process to exit, and blocks the current thread of execution until the time has elapsed or the process has exited. To avoid blocking the current thread, use the Exited event.

As stated, if you want to run code after the process has exited use the `Exited` event. Since your code does not do that you might just skip this step.